# Owncloud fails to load Qt-Platform xcb

Tags: debian, owncloud, qt

I try to run the owncloud client on my Debian desktop. I ran `apt-get install owncloud-client` to do so. But when I issue `owncloud` on the command line the following error appears:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Available platform plugins are: linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

But as I installed the package from repositories there should be no problem with broken library dependencies. To verify that I used `ldd`:

```
ldd /usr/bin/owncloud | grep xcb
```

which outputs:

```
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f190be16000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f190acd3000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f190aaba000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f190a8b5000)
libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f190a6b2000)
libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f190a4af000)
libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f190a2a8000)
```

What else can I do to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Although all dependencies are fulfilled according to the command `ldd`, they actually are not. On Debian 8 I needed to install Qt5:

```
apt-get install qt5-default
```

This solved the problem.